# Polish space is the image of $\mathcal{N}$ under a continuous function

Tags: proof-verification, descriptive-set-theory

Proposition: Each nonempty Polish space is the image of $\mathcal{N}:=\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ under a continuous function.

(See for example Donald L. Cohn "Measure Theory" on page 250)

my Question: Is the constructed function $f$ even uniformly continuous?

In the proof he shows that $d(f(m),f(n)) \leq  \frac{1}{k}$ for all $m,n \in \mathcal{N}$ with $m_i=n_i, i=1,...,k$. ($d$ denotes the metric on the Polish space).

Hence: Let $\epsilon >0$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N} \leq \epsilon$. Choose $\delta:=\frac{1}{2^n}$. Then for $m,n \in \mathcal{N}$ with $d_{\mathcal{N}}(m,n)=\sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{2^k} d_{discret}(m_k,n_k) < \delta=\frac{1}{2^N} \qquad$      ($d_{discret}$ is the discrete metric) it follows:

$d_{discret}(m_k,n_k) < 1$ for all $k=1,\dots,N$ and hence $m_k=n_k$ for $k=1,\dots,N$. So from the proof it follows that $d(f(m),f(n))\leq \frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is correct. Perhaps it is a bit easier to see it by considering the following [strongly equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics#Strong_equivalence) metric on $\mathcal{N}$ given by $d(m,m):=0$ and if $m\neq n$,
$$
d(m,n) := 2^{-\Delta(m,n)},
$$
where $\Delta(m,n)$ is the least index in which they differ.

By the strong equivalence, the notion of uniform continuity is the same for both metrics.

Comment: Thank you! I can't understand why this fact isn't mentioned in any book dealing with descreptive set theory. Maybe it's not that important for other Propositions that are based on it and they only need that the function is continuous.

Comment: I think the main reason is that “definability” issues concern the Borel hierarchy, and that is pretty much independent of the metric.